# Version control: How to incorporate changes on the main branch into a subbranch

Tags: git, version-control

Given the following git branch structure:

```
+---+ 
|   |
|   |   * commit2 
|   *   | commit1
|   |   |
+---+---+  
b1  b2  b3
```

How do I incorporate the changes of branch `b2` that have been merged into branch `b1` into the still unmerged branch `b3`? The change `commit1` has been an adaption to a new program environment so without these changes it's not possible to currently run and test the program on branch `b3`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the `git rebase` command, more info [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

`git rebase b1 b3` rebases the branch `b3` onto `b1` with the following result:

```
        * commit2
        |
+---+---+
|   |   
|   *     commit1
|   |    
+---+  
b1  b2  b3
```